# Unsigned fixed point 0.28 format

Tags: c, microcontroller, fixed-point

I found in a stepper driver datasheet [L6472](https://www.st.com/en/motor-drivers/l6472.html) the following description:

[image]

What is the "unsigned fixed point 0.28 format"?

I found information about the fixed point format itself, but what does the 0.28 mean?

Is there an easy implementation for this conversion from [step/s] to SPEED in C on a micro-controller without floating point unit?

Comment: I means that the format is as given in the equation you show form the datasheet. If you don't want to use floating-point numbers, you're best leaving the number in the format of the SPEED register. The reason for the fixed-point representation is that you need to be able to represent numbers much smaller than 1.

Comment: 0 bits before the radix point, 28 bits after it.

Comment: just use it as an integer, do the math as needed, no need for fixed point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notation *m*.*n* for a fixed-point format means there are *m* bits representing an integer portion of a number and *n* bits represent a fractional portion of a number.

If you have *m*+*n* bits interpreted as some integer *N*, then the same bits would be interpreted as an *m*.*n* fixed-point number *N*/2<sup>*n*</sup>.

So, if you have 28 bits that, when interpreted as an integer, represent a value of *N*, then, when interpreted as a 0.28 fixed-point number, they represent a value of *N*/2<sup>28</sup>.

Note that it is unusual for a register to have only 28 bits. If the register actually has 32 bits, then the high four bits should be ignored when interpreted the contents as a 0.28 fixed-point number, unless it is known they must be zero.